# D3 v7 Force Graph: Images are not showing up

Tags: javascript, image, d3.js, graph, nodes

I successfully managed to build a force graph with my data. Now I wanted to display a separate image for each node, but the two approaches I find to accomplish this won't work.

This is the first one:

```
var node = svg
.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r", entityRadius)
.call(drag(simulation))
.attr("fill", "url(#bgPattern)");

defs
.append("svg:pattern")
.attr("width", 150)
.attr("height", 150)
.attr("id", "bgPattern")
.append("svg:image")
.data(graph.nodes)
.attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
  return "../assets/images/" + d.compressed;
})
.attr("width", 150)
.attr("height", 150)
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", -20);
node.attr("fill", "url(#bgPattern)");
```

Which works, but only shows one image for some reason. The function only runs once.

And the other one is this:

```
 node
.append("image")
.attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
  return "../assets/images/" + d.compressed;
})
.attr("width", 150)
.attr("height", 150)
.attr("x", -75)
.attr("y", -75);
```

Which successfully places an individual image element inside of each circle element, but never renders it.

[Images in Circle Elements are not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWwQe.png)

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with this code?

Here is the full code with the two approaches:

```js
function blogGraph(graph) {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  const sourceRadius = 45;
  const entityRadius = 35;

  var svg = d3
    .select("#networkGraph")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(
      d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        svg.attr("transform", event.transform);
      })
    )
    .append("g");

  var simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .force(
      "link",
      d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id;
      })
    )
    .force(
      "charge",
      d3.forceManyBody().strength(-2000).theta(0.5).distanceMax(500)
    )
    .force(
      "collision",
      d3.forceCollide().radius(function (d) {
        return d.radius;
      })
    )
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  defs
    .append("radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "entity-gradient")
    .attr("cx", "50%")
    .attr("cy", "50%")
    .attr("r", "50%")
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([
      { offset: "50%", color: "#ffffff" },
      { offset: "100%", color: "#CCCCCC" },
    ])
    .enter()
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function (d) {
      return d.offset;
    })
    .attr("stop-color", function (d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  defs
    .append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("id", "bgPattern")
    .append("svg:image")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
      return "../assets/images/" + d.compressed;
    })
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -20);

  var link = svg
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line");

  link.style("stroke", "#aaa");

  var node = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    // .selectAll("img")
    // .data(graph.nodes)
    // .enter()
    // .append("img")
    // .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
    //   return "../assets/images/" + d.compressed;
    // })
    // .attr("width", 150)
    // .attr("height", 150)
    // .attr("x", -150)
    // .attr("y", -150);
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", entityRadius)
    .call(drag(simulation));
  // .attr("fill", "url(#bgPattern)");

  node
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
      return "../assets/images/" + d.compressed;
    })
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("x", -75)
    .attr("y", -75);

  node
    .style("fill-opacity", "0.5")
    // .style("fill", "#cccccc")
    .style("stroke", "#424242")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px");

  var label = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.title;
    })
    .attr("class", "label");

  label.style("text-anchor", "middle").style("font-size", function (d) {
    return d.title == "technology"
      ? Math.min(
          2 * entityRadius,
          ((2 * entityRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength()) * 15
        ) + "px"
      : Math.min(
          2 * sourceRadius,
          ((2 * sourceRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength()) * 15
        ) + "px";
  });

  label
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      tooltip.html(`${d.title}`);
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function (event) {
      return tooltip
        .style("top", event.pageY - 10 + "px")
        .style("left", event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    });

  node
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      tooltip.html(`${d.title}`);
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function (event) {
      return tooltip
        .style("top", event.pageY - 10 + "px")
        .style("left", event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });

  simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x + 5;
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y - 3;
      });

    label
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

  function drag(simulation) {
    function dragstarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.y;
    }

    function dragended(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      event.subject.fx = null;
      event.subject.fy = null;
    }

    return d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);
  }

  var tooltip = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("color", "white")
    .style("padding", "8px")
    .style("background-color", "#626D71")
    .style("border-radius", "6px")
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .style("width", "auto")
    .text("");
}

var nodesUrl = "https://www.fabianschober.com/json/nodes.json"; 
var linksUrl = "https://www.fabianschober.com/json/links.json";

Promise.all([d3.json(nodesUrl), d3.json(linksUrl)]).then((res) => {
  // console.log(res);
  blogGraph({ nodes: res[0], links: res[1] });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./ForceGraph.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="networkGraph"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: The Json Files are getting blocked by CORS, but you may get the idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. You gotta assign every pattern its own unique ID.

```
  const nodePatterns = svg
    .selectAll("pattern")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("pattern")
    .attr("id", (d) => `pattern-${d.id}`)
    .attr("width", nodeRadius)
    .attr("height", nodeRadius)
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", (d) => "../assets/images/" + d.compressed);

  var node = svg
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius)
    .style("stroke", "#424242")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .attr("fill", (d) => `url(#pattern-${d.id})`);
```